# Rails - relation between activeadmin model and custom model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, activeadmin

First I would like to know if there is any possibilities to associate one of my model with the `ActiveAdmin::Comment` and the `AdminUser` models

this is my `model`

```
class AdminAction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :comment, :class_name => "ActiveAdmin::Comment", :foreign_key => "admin_action_id"
  belongs_to :admin_user
end
```

thoses associations don't raise any errors, just returning `nil``

I have added a field in thoses two models :

```
add_column :admin_users, :admin_action_id, :integer
add_column :active_admin_comments, :admin_action_id, :integer
```

The goal here is to fetch the `AdminUser` and the `Comment` associate to my new model `AdminAction`
and when I do

```
a = AdminAction
a.admin_user 
# and 
a.comment
```

it works

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `admin_user_id` in the `admin_actions` table to make this `belongs_to` association work.

```
class AdminAction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin_user
end
```

Also, the `foreign_key` param is unneeded because it will be inferred from the `AdminAction` class name.

```
class AdminAction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :comment, :class_name => "ActiveAdmin::Comment", :foreign_key => "admin_action_id"
end
```

Other than that, what you have should work as expected. If it is not, please provide more detail as to what you are seeing, or not seeing as the case may be.

I have this working, albiet with a `User` model rather than `AdminUser`. Here is my code:

**Migrations**

```
class CreateAdminAction < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
      create_table :admin_actions do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddFieldsForAdminAction < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :active_admin_comments, :admin_action_id, :integer
  end
end
```

**`AdminAction` class**

```
class AdminAction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :comment, class_name: 'ActiveAdmin::Comment'
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Another thought: if you are looking to get the `ActiveAdmin::Comment` records for a single `AdminUser`, I think you can fetch them directly like this:

```
admin_comments = ActiveAdmin::Comment.find_for_resource_in_namespace(AdminUser.find(some_id), :admin)
```